# Jquery Mobile pass to page checkboxes checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 2 pages using jQuery Mobile framework.

One is called **types.html**, where I have a list of checkboxes.
The other is called **products.html**, where I whant to show the products regarding the types selected in the page types.html.

So, my question is: how can I pass these checked values to next page?

Thanks in advance.

**[UPDATED]**

This is the solution, as @Ved suggested. It worked! :)

```
var chk_types = [];

$('.chk_types:checked').each(function() {
   chk_types.push($(this).attr("value"));
});

localStorage.setItem("chk_types",chk_types);

$('#form').submit();
```

Comment: Can you post your code?  Do you have both your pages in the same html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On types.html store all selected value store in array variable

```
localStorage.setItem("checkboxvalue", array_variable);
```

On products.html on pageshow even OR document.ready event

```
localStorage.getItem("checkboxvalue");
```

Comment: Thanks @Ved! It worked! Please check your solution in my updated post.